# JQuery.autosave bind to events does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using https://github.com/nervetattoo/jquery-autosave plugin to add autosave functionality to my forms. I try to bind the events offered by the plugin. But they are not fired or I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. Where is my mistake?

Form:

```
<form id="myform">
   <input id="inputtext" type="text" value="test">
</form>
```

Script:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#myform').autosave({
        namespace: "myform",
        callbacks: {
            data: 'serialize',
            scope: 'all',
            save: {
                method: 'ajax',
                options: {
                    url: '#',
                    type: 'post'
                }
            }
        }

    }).bind('changed.myform', function(event, input){
        alert('changed');
    },
    'saved.myform', function (event) {
        alert('saved');
    });
});
```

A example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/smsn95cw/3/

Answer (score 0):

Chaining of event triggers does not work here..
If it's bound in a single call it works,

```
    $('#myform').bind('saved', function() {
        console.log("saved"); // not works
    });
    $('#myform').bind('saved.autosave', function() {
        console.log("saved.autosave"); //works
    });
    $('#myform').bind('save', function() {
        console.log("save"); // not works
    });
    $('#myform').bind('save.autosave', function() {
        console.log("save.autosave"); //works
    });
    $('#myform').bind('changed', function() {
        console.log("changed"); // not works
    });
    $('#myform').bind('changed.autosave', function() {
        console.log("changed.autosave"); //works
    });
```